# Calling onload function in $ionicPopup without the use of "onTap" for inserting Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, appery.io

Below is my code snippet and I wish to call a function "insertBarchart()" on loading the ionic popup. However I am not able to call without the use of "onTap" (which requires clicking the 'Show' button).

> Note: The barchart is shown at the place of "container" which is defined inside popup so function call must be made within the scope.

```
$ionicPopup = Apperyio.get("$ionicPopup");
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    scope: $scope,
    template: '<div id="container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto" ></div>',
    buttons: [{
        text : 'OK',
        type: 'button-positive'
    },
    {
        text : 'Show',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap : function(e) {
            $scope.insertBarchart();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same situation I tried in other way please check this code once

angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])

```
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $q, $ionicPopup) {
   $scope.cmnt={};
    $scope.showToast=function (message) {
    if (window.plugins && window.plugins.toast) {
        window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter(message);
    }
    else $ionicLoading.show({ template: message, noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });
}
$scope.showPopup = function () {
    $scope.data = {};
    var pop=$ionicPopup.show({
        template: '<div class="list" dir="rtl"><label class="item item-input"><input ng-model="cmnt.name" type="text" placeholder="name"></label><label class="item item-input"><textarea ng-model="cmnt.body" rows="4" placeholder="      comment..."></textarea></label></div>',
        title: 'write your comment',
        subTitle: '',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
          {
              text: 'cancel',
              type: 'button-small'

          },
          {
              text: '<b>save</b>',
              type: 'button-energized',
              onTap: function (e) {
                  return $scope.cmnt;

              }
          }
        ]
    }).then(function (res) {
       $scope.showToast(res.name);
    });


}
  });
```

Comment: I guess this runs after closing the popup. I want to show the barchart inside popup while it's been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $ionicPopup you can create a modal page in Appery that will have its own init() function and can be customized more easily